# Validating form fields submitted in rails belong to owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a model called PaymentMethods that belongs to User. When the user goes to checkout they are presented with a list of available PaymentMethods that belong to them. What is the best way to make sure a user can't manually edit the dom and use somebody else's payment method?

I'm currently using a custom validation in my model

```
def payment_method_owner?

  errors.add(:payment_method, "This card doesn't belong to you") unless self.user.payment_methods.include? self.payment_method

end
```

Is this the best way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, generally, this is a pretty good way to go.

There are a few points that may be worth mentioning, however.

Typically, when adding errors to a specific attribute, it is done with a sentence fragment that does not contain the subject. The reason for this, is because the full_messages helper concatenates the attribute name with the error. In this case, the full message would be "Payment method This card doesn't belong to you". I would suggest changing the message to just "doesn't belong to you", resulting in "Payment method doesn't belong to you". If they are getting this message, they probably know why they're getting it... An alternative to shortening the message would be to add the full error to base, but this would make the field_with_errors stuff not work in the view.

Secondly, you can remove the two `self.`s in your method, they are unnecessary.

Finally, this is, in my opinion, the perfect amount of logic for this type of validation, anything more complex would probably warrant a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators).

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
validates :payment_method, inclusion: { in: lambda{ |x| x.user.payment_methods } }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was worried this might be the best way, but was hoping rails provided some way to do this. I didn't want to have to create a method to check each parameter to make sure a user wasn't trying to pass something they shouldn't.